# Insert image path into table in access by vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to insert image path fields from SQL SERVER into table in access by vba code but it dosent run and send  run-time error 3075  , the whole fields insert successful except the path  .

```
  Dim sqlstr As String
  Dim sqlstr1 As String
  dim strSQL as string



 Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
           rs.CursorType = adOpenDynamic

        rs.LockType = adLockReadOnly
                rs.ActiveConnection = db

                DoCmd.SetWarnings False
                DoCmd.RunSQL "delete from tb_brws"
                DoCmd.SetWarnings True

           rs.Open "SELECT [sno] [imgp] from books_tb  where  [sno] like '" & Me.sno_txt & "' ;"

            rs.MoveFirst

Do
 sqlstr = rs![sno]
 sqlstr1 = rs1![imgp]
 DoCmd.SetWarnings False


   strSQL="insert into tb_brws (sno,imgp) values ('" & sqlstr & "', '" & sqlstr1 & "')"
 DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

 DoCmd.SetWarnings True

 rs.MoveNext
  Loop While Not rs.EOF



 Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Please post the resolved SQL you are trying to run. Possibly 'sno' is numeric, yet you treat as a/n? Possibly some value(s) in [imgp]... need to see final SQL.

Comment: I dont have any problem in sql , I get the value of imgp (image path) in to  text and it doesn't have any problem but when I insert it in to table it gave me syntax error and missing operator

Comment: You get an error when you try to execute the DOCMD? If so, we need to see the full string you are trying to run.

Comment: I update my code , the code done well and the sno value insert successfully into table but when I want to insert path the run-time error appear , I change the single quotation and double quotation but not work

Comment: Please add the following three lines immediately after line "sqlstr1 = rs1![imgp]", then run your code and post the MySQL string:
Dim strSQL      As String
strSQL = "insert into tb_brws (sno,imgp) values ('" & sqlstr & "', '" & sqlstr1 & "')"
 Debug.Print "MySQL: " & strSQL

Comment: I try this three line and still not work it gets the path but cannot insert it to table

Comment: The three lines of code were not intended to fix anything. They were simply to show the exact SQL that you are trying to run and which I need to see. Please post the display  of the SQL that is shown in the immediate window.

Comment: This is the error : Run-time error '3075': syntax error(missing operator) in query expression "\\user-pc\saveimage\768823\vocation\01-08-2016'123.pdf ')'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for showing the actual SQL string -- it greatly helped because it shows there is a single quote in the string (01-08-2016'123.pdf). Access thinks that is a delimiter (regardless if you enclose in double-quotes).
Please use the following code (I have tested and it works just fine).

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
' this will change any ' characters to '' which will allow the SQL to run.
sqlstr1 = Replace(sqlstr1, "'", "''")     ' REPLACE SINGLE QUOTE

strSQL = "insert into tb_brws (sno,imgp) values ('" & sqlstr & "', '" & sqlstr1 & "')"
Debug.Print "MySQL: " & strSQL
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Comment: Thanks alot its working but I delete the single quote in the path instead of add one , thanks for your help

Comment: If the file/path actually has the quote in the name, it is fine to delete by using your code, but if you don't rename the file to remove the quote, some time in the future you may scratch your head. For example, if you build some code to read the Access table and then try to open the file, you will get an error of 'File not found'.

Comment: yes,  I know I delete it from the code thanks for note